# Update Oracle Table From XMLTable

Tags: sql-server, oracle, xquery, xmltable

This is the way how i do in ms sql

```
   DECLARE @xmlData XML = N'<provinces>
    <provinceid>1</provinceid>
    <provincename>Queensland</provincename>
    <shortcode>QL</shortcode>
    <countryid>112</countryid>
    </provinces>';
```

> ```
> UPDATE rel.mProvince
> SET ProvinceName = X.provincename,
> ShortCode = X.shortcode,
> CountryID = X.countryid
> FROM rel.mProvince INNER JOIN 
> (SELECT c.value('provinceid[1]','int') [provinceid],
> c.value('provincename[1]','nvarchar(50)') [provincename],
> c.value('shortcode[1]','nvarchar(10)') [shortcode],
> c.value('countryid[1]','int') [countryid]
> FROM @xmlData.nodes('//provinces') t(c)) X ON rel.mProvince.ProvinceID = X.provinceid
> WHERE rel.mProvince.ProvinceID=X.provinceid;
> ```

now i want to update the table mProvince in Oracle below is update query

```
DECLARE xmlData XMLTYPE = XMLTYPE('<provinces>
    <provinceid>1</provinceid>
    <provincename>Queensland</provincename>
    <shortcode>QL</shortcode>
    <countryid>112</countryid>
    </provinces>');    

        UPDATE mProvince 
        SET ProvinceName = X.provincename, 
        ShortCode = X.shortcode, 
        CountryID = X.countryid 
        FROM mProvince INNER JOIN (SELECT X.* 
        FROM XMLTABLE('/NewDataSet'  
        PASSING xmlData  
        COLUMNS "provinceid" NUMBER PATH 'provinceid',  
        "provincename" NVARCHAR2(50) PATH 'provincename',  
        "shortcode" NVARCHAR2(10) PATH 'shortcode', 
        "countryid" NUMBER PATH 'countryid')) X  
        ON mProvince.ProvinceID = X.provinceid 
        WHERE mProvince.ProvinceID=X.provinceid;
```

This fails in oracle, whats wrong with it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, I am unable to understand your specific problem. You state that you can "successfully insert data into table", but you can not "update" - Isn't that a contradiction? What exactly does not work and what error message or unexpected behaviour do you get? Please add more information your question.

Comment: thanks for reply, I wish how do i do use this update query in oracle. ??

Comment: well, you execute it?! I am sorry, but with so little and imprecise information no-one will be able to help you. You **need** to improve your question.

Comment: better, we are getting closer. What does `This fails in oracle` mean - You surely are getting error messages. What does it say? In general, simply transferring your SQL code from one DBMS to another will rarely work, as not everything is part of the SQL standard.